Dropping Particular Backstack in Jetpack Compose, Kotlin
i am building an android app using jetpack compose handling navigations using navGraph
i navigated from home>scan-category>scan>scan-questions>scan-results
but i want to directly jump to scan from scan-results page...
applied various logics like implementing backhandler to use popUpTo function... but nothing works

The fact that you mentioned BackHandler at all seems to mean that you want system back, when you are on the scan result page, to go back to the scan page? Is that correct?

yes correct i want the system back @ianhanniballake

BackHandler {        navController.navigate(bottomNavItems.Scan.returnScanIndex(indexClassification)){
            popUpTo(bottomNavItems.Scan.returnScanIndex(indexClassification)){
                inclusive= true
            }}
    }

implementing above code takes back to scan page but keep looping scan and scan-result page

Can you edit your question to include the code where you navigate from scan-questions to scan-results?

navHostController.navigate( bottomNavItems.ScanResult.returnScanResIndex( level = 0, index = indexClassification ) ){ popUpTo(bottomNavItems.Scan.returnScanIndex(indexClassification)){ inclusive = false } }
